# SQL Server: Select with dynamic column

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic, dynamic-sql

I have a stored procedure with the following piece. Now I would need the exact same procedure for several different scenarios where the only difference is that instead of "policy" I will refer to another column.

In order to avoid writing multiple stored procedures, is there a way I can use a variable input to define this specific column without having to make the whole procedure dynamic ?

```
INSERT INTO @temp
(       
            ranking,
            item,
            groupCount,
            groupName
)
SELECT      RANK() OVER(ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc, policy) [Rank],
            policy, 
            COUNT(*) AS groupCount,
            'currentMonth' AS groupName
FROM        Log_PE 
WHERE       CONVERT(DATE, dateEsc, 120) >= CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), GETDATE(), 112) + '01', 112)
GROUP BY    policy
ORDER BY    groupCount desc, policy
```

Many thanks for any help with this Tim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use dynamic SQL to achieve what you desire. First, create a variable to hold the name of the column that will vary. Then, create another variable to hold the dynamically generated query. Finally, use `sp_executesql` to run this dynamic query. The code will look something like this:

```
declare @colname varchar(50) = ''

declare @query nvarchar(8000) = 'INSERT INTO @temp (ranking,item,groupCount,groupName)'
+ 'SELECT RANK() OVER(ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc,' + @colname + ') [Rank],' + @colname 
+ 'COUNT(*) AS groupCount, 'currentMonth' AS groupName FROM Log_PE'
+ 'WHERE CONVERT(DATE, dateEsc, 120) >= CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), GETDATE(),112)      
+  '01', 112)'
+ 'GROUP BY ' + @colname
+ ' ORDER BY groupCount desc, ' + @colname

execute sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: Quick question: regarding the parts that were already in quotes before, do I have to escape this by adding another quote etc. in the dynamic sql ?

Comment: Yes, you will need to escape them. Thanks for pointing that out, it had escaped my mind when answering!

Comment: Ok, great so I just need to add extra single quotes around them ?